# How to do POD install in Bamboo Continuous integration for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, bamboo

I am integration my iOS project for continuous integration through bamboo. But I have difficulties in two steps. How to do a pod install and pass the certificate for signinging. However, I have the build command which is working fine in a local machine, but how to achieve this in bamboo server. Any help appericiate.

```
#!/bin/sh
Pod install
xcodebuild -workspace my-Container.xcworkspace -configuration -Release  -scheme my-Container clean archive -archivePath build/my-Container
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/my-Container.xcarchive -exportPath build/my-Containerr.ipa -exportOptionsPlist exportoption.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

I have hard time to create my bamboo job for building. My steps ware:

1. Checkout the repo with correct branch
2. Script task with "pod install" inside. [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/a-sample-deployment-project-365658897.html)
3. xcode build task with correct properties. You need to do some additional work in order to have this build task. Check the steps [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/xcode-354353193.html)

If you command works okay as you said then maybe you can create just a script task with your code.

In my case I had problems with certificates selection and I create script like this one:

```
sed -i '' 's/ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;/ProvisioningStyle = Manual;/' MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

sed -i '' 's/CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;/CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Manual;/' MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

sed -i '' 's/CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Developer";/CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Distribution";/' MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

sed -i '' '<key>CFBundleVersion</key>= "";/PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = "Profile 1";/' MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

sed -i '' 's/ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;/ProvisioningStyle = Manual;/' MyProject/Info.plist
```

in order to build correctly

Comment: Thanks for the same. The pod install is not working pod:common not found. My initial ask is how to install the pod. Because of no pod showing pod command not found.

Comment: you need to install it on the machine where the bamboo is istalled. In my case I had remote desktop connection to it.

Comment: if you don't have access to the machine you can try to install cocoapods through a bammboo job with script task. Check this https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html for sudo-less installation

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am trying will let u know,.

Comment: Just want to verify here is my script to install pod in a remote machine.                   cat <<EOT >> $HOME/.profile
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
EOT
echo "Start installing Pod"
gem install cocoapods --user-install

Comment: It is hard to validate it because I don’t have computer in front of me. But it seams to be okay.

Comment: Looks like script is ohk, pod installation is working. But now I am seeing Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found. No idea how to install cert in a remote machine.

Comment: I don't have any good idea, about this. Somthing that you can try to do again is job with your certificates in the repo and this command   ---> add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certificate>  Maybe is not the best think that you can do.